# React remove script when component will unmount

Tags: reactjs, dom

How can I remove the previously added script from component when it will unmount?

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ScriptServices extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "./scriptServices.js";
    this.instance.appendChild(s);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // remove script
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => (this.instance = el)} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by removing the script? If you just want to remove the tag, that's feasible, but if you're looking for a way to undo whatever effects the script had on the global environment, that'd be a little bit more involved!

Comment: That script adds an iframe to DOM when loaded and that needs to be removed too..

Comment: What's the use case here for injecting the iFrame via this script rather than managing it via a React component? Also -- similar to what @JoeClay points out, even if you remove the script, if the code has been loaded by the client machine, removing the script tag probably won't have any effect on the iFrame

Comment: @Sam I'm loading a form created with `JotForm` (for example https://form.jotform.com/81003857231348), that's why I need to inject the iFrame

Comment: Is there any way to add the source code of that form directly in React Component?

Comment: Is this a try to do code splitting and [dynamic importing](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)? This is supported by webpack. Normally if you do not care for bundle size you do not need to dynamically load javascript. Just create a component that creates an iframe with the desired content and then conditionally render that component. No need to manually remove anything.

Comment: @trixn I don't care for bundle size and I think that your approach would work. But how can I add the source code of the iframe to the component? https://github.com/alpesh-jikadra/Resources/blob/master/js/81003857231348.js

Comment: Do you expect that I read 53465454 lines of minified javascript code? :) Usually an iframe is a page in a page. That means you set the source and it will load an individual page inside that. Of course there must be a route for that in your backend.